# Default value of char is said to be '\u0000' but I got the output space character (' ') in java

Tags: java, char, default-value

> Here is the code I got the space output. I didn't figure out if '\u0000' means the space or something else.

```
`package com.string.test;   
 class CharTest {   
   char y;   
   public static void main(String args[]){  
     CharTest test = new CharTest();   
     System.out.println("Default value of char:----" + test.y + "----");   
   }   
} `
```

Comment: Not wanting to use my hammer, but this doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.  The question here is "has it changed in Java 8".  OP seems to know that it was the null character (that is, `\u0000`, not Java null) previously.

Comment: I am not getting null output for default char.Please try some code in java 8 and correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that you tried, so someone can point out why it doesn't give you what you expect?  I don't think anybody is going to come to this site, and write code to prove to themselves what they already know.

Comment: I have posted the code below.

Comment: {
package com.string.test; 

 class CharTest {
  char y; 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   CharTest test = new CharTest(); 
   System.out.println("Default value of char:----" + test.y + "----"); 
  } 
 } //please check this code i got space output 
}

Comment: @PrayagSharma If you have another question, then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a _new_ question. Don't edit another ones closed question, just to match your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

A char has a default value of 'u0000'.
Reference this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html